# Grep in bash with regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am getting the following output from a bash script:

```
INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist
```

and I would like to get only the path(MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist) using grep. In other words, everything after the equals sign. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying "I want everything after the equals sign"? You need `sed`, not `grep` for that - editing the line (not just selecting it).

Comment: Yes. Everything after the equals sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This job suites more to awk:

```
s='INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist'
awk -F' *= *' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist
```

If you really want `grep` then use `grep -P`:

```
grep -oP ' = \K.+' <<< "$s"
MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist
```

Comment: You could make it _slightly_ a question about bash by using `awk ... <<<"$s"` rather than `echo "$s" | awk`. :)

Comment: ...it's also worth noting that `grep -P` is very, _very_ nonstandard, and not available on several widely-used platforms (including even some Linux distros using GNU grep, since it's a compile-time option not every distro turns on).

Comment: Both valid points, I would prefer awk above and over grep any day.

Comment: In my opinion, of all the built in text processing commands, `awk` is _the_ power tool. I thought in this case it might be a slight overkill, but it needs to be in everyone's toolkit. But for this task I gravitate to `sed`. Maybe because I learnt it first?

Comment: The awk solution won't print the entire right side of the string if it contains another `=` sign.

Comment: It appears to be a variable assignment text which can have only one `=`

Comment: Variable values may contain the `=` character. So can file names.

Comment: I will let OP mention it then awk can be tweaked easily for that scenario.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why not give a fully working answer without waiting for the OP to discover a bug, especially one that may be hidden for a while?

Comment: Because if it works for OP then why make it complicated.

Comment: Just for your satisfaction that awk will be: `awk -F'^.* = *' '{print $2}'`

Comment: I'm afraid that only prints the part after the *last* `=` sign.

Comment: Use `awk -F'^[^=]*= *' '{print $2}'` in that case.

Comment: Thanks!
I wasn't trying to be hard on your answer. I have a simple mental test that goes something like "if someone writes a tool based on my answer and I have to use that tool, would I rest assured that it won't fail me when I can least afford it?"

Comment: @anubhava please explain `-F' *= *'` part.The `*` is confusing me.

Comment: That means 0 or more spaces on either side of `=` character.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you were asking, but

```
echo "INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist" | sed 's/.*= \(.*\)$/\1/'
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Althogh, it is still printing out the full output form echo(INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist).

Comment: Might need `sed -r` to enable ERE support.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it might be that my (OSX) version of `sed` is slightly different. For example, it needs `-E` not `-r` for ERE. But yes, those difference can be really annoying in what is supposed to be a standard tool.

Comment: Or just use `sed 's/[^=]\+=\s*//'` and there's no need for the capture.

Comment: @Emmet - that's a really good and simple alternative. `<headslap>`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `cut` as well:

```
your_script | cut -d = -f 2-
```

(where `your_script` does something equivalent to `echo INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist`)

If you need to trim the space at the beginning:

```
your_script | cut -d = -f 2- | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

If you have multiple spaces at the beginning **and you want to trim them all**, you'll have to fall back to sed: `your_script | cut -d = -f 2- | sed 's/^ *//'` (or, simpler, `your_script | sed 's/^[^=]*= *//'`)

Comment: Output will have a space also: `<space>MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist`

Comment: Still doesn't work for `echo 'INFOPLIST_FILE =  MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist'|cut -d = -f 2- | cut -d ' ' -f 2-` case.

Comment: Actually, after giving it some thought, based on the OP example, that is a legitimate case and works as intended. If you have more than one space after `=`, you probably only want to trim the first one, as the subsequent ones are likely part of the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your script outputs a single line, there is a shell only solution:

```
line="$(your_script)"
echo "${line#*= }"
```

Comment: +1. Only thing you might change here is stripping leading whitespace, since the example is using `key = value` rather than `key=value`.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Also quoted it in case multiple or trailing spaces need to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Bash

```
IFS=' =' read -r _ x <<<"INFOPLIST_FILE = MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist"
printf "%s\n" "$x"
MajorDomo/MajorDomo-Info.plist
```